# Issue with ARM template for Creating SFTP-SSH connector

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Currently I am trying to Create a SFTP-SSH connector for one of the Logic App. I got a Reference for SFTP connector

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-logic-app-ftp-to-blob/azuredeploy.json

When i am trying to create the connector with the below code

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
      "apiVersion": "2018-07-01-preview",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "name": "[parameters('ftpConnectionName')]",
      "properties": {
        "api": {
          "id": "[subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis', parameters('location'), 'ftp')]"
        },
        "displayName": "ftp",
        "parameterValues": {
          "serverAddress": "[parameters('ftpServerAddress')]",
          "userName": "[parameters('ftpUsername')]",
          "password": "[parameters('ftpPassword')]",
          "serverPort": "[parameters('ftpServerPort')]",
          "isssl": "[variables('ftpisssl')]",
          "isBinaryTransport": "[variables('ftpisBinaryTransportftpisssl')]",
          "disableCertificateValidation": "[variables('ftpdisableCertificateValidation')]"
        }
      }
    }
```

Getting the below Error:-

```
"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"Input parameters are invalid. See details for more information. 
Details:errorCode: ParameterNotDefined. Message: Parameter  'serverAddress' is not allowed on the connection since it 
was not defined as a connection parameter when the API was registered..","Target":null,"Details":[{"Message":"Input 
parameters are invalid
```

It says "serverAddress" is wrong param. Any one have any idea regrading this?

***NB:-*** All of the parameters are declared in Parameter file. Its simple SFTP address String.

Comment: Any Help here i can get?

Comment: You can contact MSDN support. Found one similar issue there with different connector. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f4cd2d31-2bfe-4d61-8c6c-f6ebedc14b92/sql-connector-parameternotdefined-error?forum=azurelogicapps

Comment: Raised a question in MSDN Forum
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/44fb21f5-72b2-4304-b4cf-3753a7d21525/issue-with-sftp-arm-template?forum=opensourcedevwithazure

Answer (score 0):

It should be 'hostName' not 'serverAddress' if you are trying to create SFTP-SSH connector